# How to use environment variables in Windows container with Powershell

Tags: powershell, docker, dockerfile

In a Windows docker container I'm trying to set an environment variable based on a build argument.

I have tried this:

```
docker build --build-arg MYVAR="test" .
```

In the Dockerfile I have:

```
#escape=`

ARG MYVAR
ENV MYENVVAR {`"endpointCredentials`": [{`"password`": `"$Env:MYVAR`"}]}
```

But when I run `Get-Item $Env:MYVAR` I get:

```
{"endpointCredentials": [{"password":":MYVAR"}]}
```

What I want is

```
{"endpointCredentials": [{"password":"test"}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--build-arg` is to pass arguments to the Dockerfile, so you need to configure the `MYVAR` as an argument in the Dockerfile:

```
ARG MYVAR
ENV MYENVAR {`"endpointCredntials`": [{`"password`": "$MYVAR"}]}
```

Comment: I already had `ARG MYVAR` in my Dockerfile, I just forgot to mention it. Question updated.

Comment: But in the second line don't use `$Env:MYVAR`, just use `$MYVAR` or `${MYVAR}`